# Python - DDL program if statement causing name error when using y/n instead of 1/2

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x

A simple ddl program however when response uses y or n I get a name error saying that eg. y is not defined. When I change the code to use 1 or 2 the program runs fine. I am confused at how y or n can throw up a name error, I have tried defining the input result as a string but it still gave a name error.

```
import sqlite3
#
def create_table(db_name,table_name,sql):
    with sqlite3.connect(db_name) as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('select name from sqlite_master where name=?',(table_name,))
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        keep_table = True
        if len(result) == 1:
#Problem area
            response = input('The table {0} already exists, do you wish to overide? (y/n): '.format(table_name))
            if response == 'y':
#Problem area end
                keep_table = False
                cursor.execute('drop table if exists {0}'.format(table_name))
                print('Table overwritten')
                db.commit()
            else:
                print('Table kept')
        else:
            keep_table = False
        if not keep_table:
            cursor.execute(sql)
            db.commit()
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    db_name = 'coffee_shop.db'
    sql = '''create table Product
             (ProductID integer,
             Name varchar(30),
             Price real,
             primary key(ProductID))'''
    create_table(db_name,'Product',sql)
```

Error message

```
The table Product already exists, do you wish to overide? (y/n): y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "coffee_shop_v2.db", line 34, in <module>
    create_table(db_name,'Product',sql)
  File "coffee_shop_v2.db", line 13, in create_table
    response = input('The table {0} already exists, do you wish to overide? (y/n): '.format(table_name))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

Comment: Some of the tags you've assigned are not relevant to the specific question you're asking. Please consider removing those. Also, your problem area is clearly not with the ddl. It would have been helpful for you to include the error message you're seeing also.

Comment: Why not use `?` with the second `cursor.execute`? Using straight `.format` increases your chance of having an SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `raw_input` instead of `input`. Input `eval`s the response which is clearly not what you're looking for.

See

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input